# I want tocreate the web page using only <div>, want to open 3 links in the right side of same page

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #div1{ /*add styles to div1*/
        width:100%;
        height:90px;
        background-color: black;
        color:orange;
    }
    #div2{ /*add styles to div2*/
        width:30%;
        height:500px;
        background-color: pink;
        color:black;
        float:left;
        padding-top: 20px
    }
    #div3{/*add styles to div3*/
        width:70%;
        height:500px;
        background-color:purple;
        color:black;
        float:right;
        padding-top: 20px
    }
    #div4{/*add styles to div4*/
        width:100%;
        height:30px;
        background-color: gray;
        color:orange;
        float:left;
    }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="div1">
</div>
<div id="div2"> 
    <h2>Menu Bar</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="link1.html" target="div3">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="link2.html" target="div3">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="link3.html" target="div3">contacts</a></li>
    </ul>   
</div>
<div id="div3" name="div3">
</div>
<div id="div4">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to open the 3 links in right side of the same web page, when click links open in another web page. I use the target of `<a>` tag as the name of the `div3`. `div3` is the id of the `<div>` where I want to open these links

Comment: You're not specific in what even your question is. If you are having an issue, be specific - post a fiddle, explain what is happening, what have you done, etc. This isn't a place for people to do your work for you

Comment: Have you looked at using an IFrame?

Answer (score 2):

In the following [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y8y5ww02/), I've created a script that targets an `iframe` inside `#div3`, so that it displays your desired page.

I have included the jQuery library, added an `iframe` to the code, written the following script:

```
$(document).on('click', '#div2 a', function(e){
    $('#div3 iframe').attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

And added the following CSS:

```
#div3 iframe{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry for my mistake i've done when asking the question.                                                                                                        Thank you, iframe worked